# conditional validate on password update in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp, passwords

In the user registration form, I have password and password2 so that user has to enter password 2x and they have to equal each other before he/she is registered. The validation rules work fine in this case. In the update user info form. I have both password and password2 set to blank so that if the user does not enter a value in the first password field or password2 field, then the system simply saves the current password which I have stored in a temporary variable in my user model. So far so good. What I want is to trigger all the same validation rules as when registering but ONLY if the user enters a value in the first password field, but leave blank and ignore otherwise. So I guess this is some kind of conditional validation.

In the user model:

```
$validate = array(
'password' =>  array(                           
'password_notempty'=>array(
'rule' => 'notEmpty',
 'message' => 'Required field',
 'on' => 'create')
 ,
 'password_between'=>array(
 'rule' => array('between', 5, 15),
 'message' => 'Between 5 to 15 characters',
 'on' => 'create')
 ,
'password_alphanumeric'=>array(
'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
'message' => 'Characters and numbers only',
'on' => 'create')
),
'password2' => array(
'password2_isequal' =>array(
'rule' => array('comparePasswords','password'),
'message' => 'Must be same value as password.')
)
);
```

Anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

this should help getting you started:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

you can also look at the code for examples on how to create the validation needed.

basically you always use a different field and only map it to the real field if something is actually entered. also dont forget to include a confirmation field (to retype and confirm the correctly typed password)

the article describes how you can achieve all that will a behavior in 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks. What I did was take the easy way out. I separated out the password and user information into separate forms. That way, if the user decides to update the password, they will be bound by the same rules as create. So in this modified setup, I was able to remove the 'on'=>'create' restriction in the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
read below url :-

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1143/Data-Validation

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1152/Core-Validation-Rules
```

//Or Try this:-

```
$validate = array(
'new_password' => array(
    'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 20),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'You password must be between 7 and 20 characters long')),
'password' => array(
    'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 20),
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'You password must be between 7 and 20 characters long')),
 'retype_password'=>array(
    'rule'=>array('equalTo','password'),
    'message'=>'Password does not match'),
'repeat_password'=>array(
    'rule'=>array('equalTo','new_password'),
    'message'=>'Password does not match'),           
);
```